# Did you listen to the DIY podcast today?

Tags: discussion

Did any of you home improvement folks catch the podcast today.  I had a great time.  Had a few tech problems getting started, but went great after a bit.   Hope I did the site proud.  Looking forward to the blog thing if someone teaches me how to use it!  lol.  If you didn't hear it live, check it out on the site.  Love to get some feedback.   Thanks to Alex, Jeff and crew, you guys were fantastic, especially putting up with a "civilian".  Too funny!!!

Comment: Here's the link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-10/

Comment: I'm listening to it now - nice job! You've got a good 'radio voice', and apparently an infinite list of interesting stories.

Comment: my wife always said I have a great face for radio. lol

Answer (score 6):

Just finished listening to the recording.  Great job!  Always nice to put a voice to the name.  And of the few that I've listened to, this has to be the most entertaining.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I for one thoroughly enjoyed it, but I am biased! Thanks Steve!

It is great to find those like Steve from *far* outside the field of programming (or computers in general) who enjoy teaching and learning from others online in our "just the facts" Q&A format. I see you get the same sense of satisfaction out of leaving a breadcrumb trail for other intrepid travellers to find as we do!

(Though I suspect we should be thanking Steve's son Alex a lot for introducing him to the network as well :) )

Comment: Did you see my comment in chat about getting Steve some cards he can hand out to colleagues and friends in the business?

Comment: @ChrisF: And maybe even to his home-inspection customers.

Comment: @chris yep, we're on it

Comment: Thanks - been off line for a couple of days and didn't have chance to check the podcast chat room before I left.

Comment: @ChrisF @Vebjorn: Those are excellent ideas! I would have loved it if my home inspector had given me a referral to such a great resource.

Comment: Cards are a great idea.  lots of my customers would love this site.

Answer (score 1):

It was great! Thanks for coming on the podcast, Steve.

I agree with you that it would be good if we could attract more pros. In the beginning, they would have to be people like you, who take pity on us poor homeowners and would like to help us. Once there are a good number of pros here, they would also benefit from asking questions (like you do now on [TOHpro](http://community.thisoldhouse.com/)).

My hope is that a site with both homeowners and pros will be viable and of interest to both groups. The StackExchange system has certainly worked well for StackOverflow, where there are programmers of every level of experience and skill.

But how do we start the process of [Attracting experts/pros/contractors?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/attracting-experts-pros-contractors) Do we just have to wait for more pros to be introduced to the site by their programmer sons, or are there effective ways of recruiting people like yourself? Do you have friends that could be interested?